# MAC OS AppleScript - Installing Java silently?

Tags: java, macos, installation, applescript, silent-installer

**Hello,**

I am creating an AppleScript where it is easy to install Java with one-click for the clients. When the AppleScript is executed it will check for Java and if not found download and install it automatically. It is fine until the downloading part. The below can be done in Terminal console manually to run silently,

```
sudo -S installer -verbose -pkg your_installer_file.pkg -target /
```

What I want is to do this in AppleScript automatically. What is the code line to achieve what is done in Terminal console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run a shell command with `sudo` privileges you have 2 options:

- With [the usual GUI] password *prompt*:

```applescript
do shell script "installer -verbose -pkg your_installer_file.pkg -target /" ¬
  with administrator privileges
```

- Fully automated, with sudo (username and) password hard-coded into your statement [NOT RECOMMENDED for obvious reasons]:

```applescript
do shell script "installer -verbose -pkg your_installer_file.pkg -target /" ¬
  user name "{SudoUserHere}" password "{PasswordHere}"  ¬
  with administrator privileges
```

If the executing user is the desired sudo user, the `user name` clause is optional.